# Ubuntu stopped finding my SSD

Tags: 18.04, uefi, ssd

I have a 3 years old Lenovo Miix 720 which I installed Ubuntu (18.04 iirc) at the beginning of the year. It ran normally and I used it as a secondary machine, that means it wasn't as busy anymore.

Now i haven't used it for quite a time and when I want to boot it up the first thing I see us the GRUB menu (Ubuntu, Advanced options for Ubuntu, UEFI Firmware Settings) where I choose the first option and it ends up in the following error message:

[image]

it also doesn't start up when I use recovery mode.
When I enter `ls /dev` I realized it doesn't show my drive (sda), therefore I assume Ubuntu can't detect my drives anymore. Since GRUB starts up and in my UEFI Settings I still can see the NVMe Drive in my boot options (if that is a valid indicator) I would rule out a mechanical problem.

My next step was to load a USB stick with a Gparted Live image and check if there is anything wrong with my partitions. The result was, that neither parted nor df seems to find any partition, not even a disk. in the gparted menu i could only find the USB stick.

I made another attempt with a Ubuntu install image, checking if I could reinstall Ubuntu. But here I got the message that I have to deactivate iRST, which I did because I already installed Ubuntu a few months ago. I also double checked with my UEFI and indeed, the SATA Controller was set to AHCI.

So this is now the end of my ideas therefore I hope someone could help me with this. Following a quick overview of some of my current UEFI Settings:

- Sata Controller set to AHCI (as opposed to RAID)
- Boot Mode: Legacy Support, UEFI first
- Boot Order: USB first, Ubuntu second, NVMe Samsung SSD third

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but I changed SATA controller to AHCI and it helped

Comment: It is set to AHCI, see my post.